# How many objects are created - Java

Tags: java, object

I am having discussion about how many objects are created in the following example. I believe there should be 5 but i am not quite sure.

```
class Test {
   int a;  int b;
   Test(){
   }
   Test(int a_, int b_){
      a=a_; b=b_;
   }
   Test(Test r){
      a=r.a; b=r.b;
   }
   void povecaj() {
      a++; b++;
   }
   Test dodaj(Test r)
      Test t = new Test(a+r.a, b+r.b);
      return t;
   }
}

// ...
Test t1 = new Test();
Test t2 = new Test(1, 2);
t1.povecaj();
Test t3 = new Test(t2);
t1 = t1.dodaj(t3);
t2 = t3;
```

Comment: @MarkSeygan 4 objects?

Comment: And why do you think the answer is 5?

Comment: @Tom i tought t2 = t3; creates new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New objects can be created [explicitly or implicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Implicit creation can occur with string literals, string concatenation, autoboxing. In Java 8, it can also occur with method reference expressions and lambda expressions.

**The code you show does not include any implicit object creation. Nor does it call any external code that might create objects.**

Therefore, all of your objects created by this code are created explicitly, by calling `new`. **This code calls `new` four times, so four objects are created.**

```
Test t1 = new Test();      // One 
Test t2 = new Test(1, 2);  // Two
t1.povecaj();
Test t3 = new Test(t2);    // Three
t1 = t1.dodaj(t3);         // Four, in the method implementation
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you created 4 objects of type `Test` with your little program. In this simple program you can easily count the number of the occurrence of the `new` keyword.

You can check this by either debugging through the code ... or by maintaining a static count variable:

```
class Test {
    static int count; // used for counting instance creations

    int a;
    int b;

    Test() {
        count += 1; // new instance created => increment count
    }

    Test(int a_, int b_) {
        this(); // Absolutely needed to have the counter incremented!
        a = a_;
        b = b_;
    }

    Test(Test r) {
        this(); // Absolutely needed to have the counter incremented!
        a = r.a;
        b = r.b;
    }

    void povecaj() {
        a++;
        b++;
    }

    Test dodaj(Test r) {
        Test t = new Test(a + r.a, b + r.b);
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        Test t2 = new Test(1, 2);
        t1.povecaj();
        Test t3 = new Test(t2);
        t1 = t1.dodaj(t3);
        t2 = t3;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

This prints

> 4